# Jquery get next element using $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html:

```
<div class="container1" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="row1" style="text-align:right;background-color:orangered;color: white;">
        <div style="text-align:center;padding:5px;" class='butopenclose'>
            <div id="grupo" style="display:inline-block;width:80%;">
                Name
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;">
                <i id="icon" class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="openclose" style="border:0px solid black;display:none">            
        <div class="container1" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
            <div class="row1" style="text-align:right;background-color:orangered;color: white;">
                <div style="text-align:center;padding:5px;" class='butopenclose'>
                    <div id="grupo" style="display:inline-block;width:80%;">
                        Name
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;">
                        <i id="icon" class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="openclose" style="border:0px solid black;display:none">
                    aaaa            
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to show the div when the users clicks into the div
with class 'butopenclose'. But i have the same div inside this div. And i cant find the next div to show.

im doing this:

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.butopenclose', function () {        
       $(this).next(".openclose").slideToggle();  
    });
```

The first div works, but the nested one no..

What i want is to get the closest div with class 'openclose' and shows it. (i tried with closest, but to use closest i have to put the parent(), and then he gets the first div and not the nested one.

Some ideas how to get the closest div ofthe button?

thanks in advance!

Rafael S.

Comment: Make your code a snippet so it can run on this page.

Comment: What about `$(this).parent().next()`?

Comment: You need to read about the tree traversing methods in jquery https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: I would go with `$(this).closest('.row1').next('.openclose').toggleSlide();`

Comment: Hello people! After some tests, the answer of @MoshFeu is the right one! My problem is that the fields inside the div were not loading, and the jquery did not show nothing.!! Now its working :)

Comment: Glad to head :)